# Does Zmanda support backup Event Scheduler?

Tags: backup, mysql, event-scheduler, amanda

I've been digging up the [Zmanda Wiki](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/Zmanda_Recovery_Manager_for_MySQL_Users_Manual), but cannot find out any option to backup the event scheduler (`--events, -E`).

Does Zmanda support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to do it in [logical backup](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/How_to_Backup#Logical) mode and add that option to the [`--extra-mysqldump-options`](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/Mysql-zrm-backup#Backup_Method_Options):

**`/etc/mysql-zrm/BackupSet/mysql-zrm.conf`**

```
backup-mode=logical
replication=1
all-databases=1
exclude-pattern="performance_schema"
ssh-user="mysql"
host="1.2.3.4"
port="3306"
mysql-binlog-path=/data/var/log/mysql
routines=1
single-transaction=never
extra-mysqldump-options="--lock-all-tables --triggers --events"
copy-plugin=/usr/share/mysql-zrm/plugins/ssh-copy.pl
```